# Optimal PostgreSQL setup for Windows 2008 R2

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 setup on Windows 2008 R2 64bit with 96 gigs of RAM and 8 cores. What would the optimal settings be for `shared_buffers`, `effective_cache_size`, `work_mem`, etc.? I realize that these values vary a lot between Linux and Windows so any help for best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also how many cores are we talking about on the CPU?

Comment: Another important thing: do *not* run a virus scanner on a DB server!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the consensus is that shared_buffers is less important to increase on Windows than it is on Linux.  Again a lot of this is very workload specific.

I would probably start with a max connections of 20 unless you have a lot of idle connections as the norm.  Start with defaults for `work_mem` and `shared_buffers` and experiment with tweaking upwards.  Always run test queries twice and discard the first one just to ensure comparable caching.  `work_mem` should be tweaked upwards if you have a lot of sorts or aggregates which would use a lot of memory per operation.  `shared_buffers` may need to go higher if you need to reserve more space in memory specifically for PostgreSQL.  However assuming you aren't running anything else that is a memory hog on the machine, I would start with default values and see how far those get you.  In most setups these should be sufficient for decent performance (occasionally even on Linux, lower `shared_buffers` can be helpful) and then watch for problems.